# Function to convert ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes into phone codes using associative arrays

Tags: php

I am writing a php function to convert ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 codes into the country telephone code. My challenge is that when I call the function, just the + symbol shows up. How do I get the numbers too to show up? Below is the code i used, just that I've reduced the number of countries.

```
<?php

function ctryarray($data)
{
 $redata = "";

$country['AF'] = "+93";
$country['AL'] = "+355";
$country['DZ'] = "+213";
$country['AS'] = "+1";

$redata = $country[$data];
return $redata;

}
?>

//Then I use the following code to call it:

$countrycode = ctryarray($ccode);
```

where $ccode is the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code.

Comment: There's no way it's a problem in the shown code.  If a problem of the kind you describe exists it must be somewhere else.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

While the code you provided doesn't show the error your describe, it could probably be condensed a bit, and it should also have some error-checking:

```
function ctryarray($data) {
  $country['AF'] = "+93";
  $country['AL'] = "+355";
  $country['DZ'] = "+213";
  $country['AS'] = "+1";

  if (array_key_exists($data,$country)) {
    return $country[$data];
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Not with the information you've given here, because that works perfectly (tested), but somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Thanks guys, you guys were all right, I studied by code a bit more carefully and realised i switched it with a function that returns an array. I appreciate your help